# c++ array copy showing errors in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, copy

```
int a[4] = {10,20,30,40};
std::vector<int> vec(4);
std::copy(a, a + 4, vec.begin());
```

I'm getting the following errorin vc++, it says warning but flagged as error how shall I solve this ?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C4996   `std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate`: Call to
>   `std::copy` with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on
>   the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable
>   this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how
>   to use Visual C++ 'Checked
>   Iterators'    ConsoleApplication3 e:\programs\vc\include\xutility 2372

Comment: Use `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)`. As it stands you're prescribing the size with `a+4`, and what happens if you fat finger `a+5` in there?

Comment: std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), vec.begin()); is also showing the same error.

Comment: `std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(vec))`

Comment: Did you do what the compiler told you to do?

Comment: The code compiles for me. I am using VS10. Which VS version are you using? Does the flag "Treat warnings as error" is turned on ? You can also disable specific warnings using #pragma warning(disable: xxxx).

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 14.0.25425.01 update 3. @NathanOliver added the preprocessor #define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS but still getting the same errror.

Comment: Here some solutions for std::copy(std::equal and etc...) to copy to c-arrays https://codeyarns.com/2010/08/30/visual-c-c4996-warning-on-copy-with-array-parameters/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, MSVC deprecate certain APIs it deems unsafe.  Basically, raw memory access where a mistake in a single parameter could lead to buffer overruns on the reading or writing side.

Among them is `std::copy`.

Calling a deprecated API leads to MSVC generating an error message.

You can disable this deprecation with `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` as the error suggests.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063174/1774667) may solve your problem; it involves wrapping the raw pointer with a "checked array iterator", which means that (at least in debug) you get assertions and/or exceptions instead of memory corruption if you get it wrong.

Buffer overruns are one of the more pervasive errors in C/C++ applications; treat them as a serious problem, even if it has runtime cost, unless and until you prove that a given path is performance critical.  At that point, find a way to statically prove your array sizes are correct.

Comment: I think this answer is too kind to VC++.  It should make it clear that std::copy is NOT deprecated in the C++ Standard, but merely frowned upon by Microsoft.  It should be easier to make VC++ mind its own business.  Whenever I get a "deprecated" warning from VC++, I always do a web search to find out if it is reeeeally deprecated.

Comment: I think you misread the warning. std::copy isn't deprecated by VC++. The use of raw pointers (unchecked iterators) with std::copy in secure code is. And rightly so.

Answer (score 3):

A safe way to call copy without risk of making a mistake with the size. I would presume that the compiler wouldn't warn about this:

```
int a[] = {10,20,30,40};
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Your code, while not perfect, is well formed and a standard compliant compiler should compile it. Perhaps you have enabled an option that treats warnings as errors.

The warning message describes how to disable the warning.